# Why is there a 16gb blank volume space on my primary partition on C: Drive?

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, partitioning, disk-management

TL:DR - Can I delete the 16gb volume on my c: drive that isn't assigned to anything, without bricking my system? It is to the left of my "Healthy (EFI System Partition)"

The only reason why I have noticed this now is because I went to back up my laptop (as I want to set up a dual boot with Linux) & the backup software (easeus) reported an error with an unknown partition with no letter assigned to the drive. Already tried to search for an answer to this error message to no avail.

With some investigation , I've come to realise that it must be this 16gb volume on my c: drive that doesn't seem to be assigned to anything. I've searched on google and haven't found anyone with the same issue so far. It's not unallocated, it just looks like it's not assigned to anything, but it's to the left of the efi system partition.

But I'm sure when I first set up my laptop that wasn't there. Only thing I can think of is when I had to send my laptop off for repair a while back. I backed it up beforehand and then when I got it back I restored it from the backup using Paragon, though I don't believe that would cause this.

So can I delete this volume? As that is the only option available when I right-click on it (& of course the help option)

Or is there a way I can see what is stored on this volume so I can decide whether I want to delete it or not?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Boot a (linux, hiren, whatever) CD and get some actual information on it. What format, how much used. Just because windows/ windows software doesn't recognise it, DOES NOT mean it is *blank*.

Then use a low-level tool to back up your drive as-it-is. This is partition, OS and FS independent.

iirc, windows calls *partitions* C: D: etc, not physical drives, so I'm not entirely sure what you're looking at. "to the left" would generally be interpreted as "at the beginning of the drive" But you could have partitions C: through Q: by carving up one physical drive...

Seems possible/likely it's a recovery partition. OEMs and windowses likes making those.

It takes a lot to "brick" a system.
It doesn't, however, take much to upset windows.
Either way, In your situation I would expect/plan a clean install of everything.

Comment: hey thanks for your reply, in the meantime i have used easeus partition manager as someone else advised elsewhere and I can see that it is a recovery partition. But what is strange , is that I already have a recovery partition on the drive. And the recovery partition is like 420~mb but this one that is 16gb , only 400~mb is actual data on it (folders, files etc.). You reckon it's ok to merge them or something? (also not sure if the image I attached is working, but it should be linked into "disk management screen" in my op)

Comment: just to add to my reply and clarify, easeus partition manager, shows that one of the recovery partitions is named "winre" and the other is "recovery". But both are recovery partition types apparently.

Comment: Yes, both are part of the recovery system and both are *needed* if you ever need/want to use that feature.

Comment: I haven't seen that before... but then I haven't dealt with windows since 7, and in that instance I forced it to install into one partition, so it didn't get to make whatever "recovery" crap it wanted to.

Windows makes many redundant copies of things, winsxs, "restore points" etc. 
It's likely that amount of space is needed to do some kind of copy-on-write snapshot kind of thing...I don't know how it "works", but based on the above comment, I wouldn't just delete it.

And while you can comfortably install most (all?) linux distros on 16gb... I'd give it more.

Comment: @mitts Recovery systems with multiple partitions are preinstalled by manufacturers, not by user installed Windows.

Comment: @ChanganAuto thanks, ok I definitely won't delete it then. But could I resize it and make it smaller without causing an issue? & potentially use the partition assistant to move it next to the other recovery partition? As I think this is what is causing the error with the backup software - ended up having to do a sector by sector backup.

Comment: @mitts thanks, yeah that partition isn't for linux i've got enough space on the c: drive. I was more concerned that if the backup software is already having issues because of this partition, is it going to cause issues when i'm trying to back up a dual-boot system

Comment: No, you can't do either action. That partition contains an image of the original installation. It isn't user accessible. If you try to mess with it it'll "break", the recovery system no longer works. It can't be moved either, not because of its "nature" but because the layout of drive makes it obvious it can't be moved with deleting other partitions.

Comment: @ChanganAuto oh ok I understand, I'm assuming it's probably due to when I first had to wipe the system before I sent it off to get repaired probably. In any case, I guess I'm safe in saying that it's not really something to be concerned about before progressing with setting up a dual-boot with linux?

Comment: Indeed, it shouldn't be a problem for dual-booting.

Comment: @ChanganAuto thanks for your assistance! not sure how I mark this as solved

Comment: You may accept this answer by @mitts if you think it was useful.